# Upload fails in PHP using Malsup's jQuery File Upload Progress Bar

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using [Malsup's jQuery File Upload Progress Bar](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/progress2.html) for visualizing progress bar while uploading files to server. I am using it now at present. I have got the following doubts in this plugin:

1) File uploads even if the progress bar has not achieved 100%

2) If the File size is more than 10 MB, it loads upto 100% in the progress bar and echoes Upload failed! message.

Here is the code :

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Uploads</title>
<style>
body { padding: 30px }
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }

.progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
.bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
.percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form action="file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myfile[]" multiple><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    </form>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
        //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
_uacct = "UA-850242-2";
urchinTracker();
</script>
```

The form action -> file.php code :

```
<?php
$upload_directory = "../users/Files/";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory . $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
    print "<br><br>";
    print "<font color='black'>File Uploaded Successfully</font>";
    print "<br><br>";
    print "<font color='black'>Uploaded File is {$_FILES['userfile']['name']} and its size is {$_FILES['userfile']['size']} bytes </font>";
} else {
    print "Upload failed!";
}
?>
```

My server settings for File Uploads:

```
post_max_size            1050M   1050M

upload_max_filesize  1050M   1050M

upload_tmp_dir           /tmp    /tmp
```

Settings in php.ini :

```
max_execution_time = 30 ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds

max_input_time = -1

memory_limit = 2000M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your php page, add this line after php tag.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: If it's actually getting to the point of complaining about the upload failing, I'm not sure it's timing out...

Comment: After 30 secs, php script will stop even if it has not uploaded the complete file and echo the response back to the ajax function that it failed.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha, thank you for the reply. I have added this tag, even though if the file size limit is more than 10 MB, it is showing Upload Failed! message..

Comment: I checked the demo. Its buggy. Progress bar doesnt work properly. Tested from chrome.

Comment: Its working good, I liked it because, its simple without any Flash etc, I am not able to figure it out, as is it a problem of Server or jQuery script!? Can it be possible that these scripts might have some code which restricts the file upload size limit? I have checked the code but didn't find any..

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. I am not getting the proper documentation for this script. Send me the link if you know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18972/discussion-between-highlander141-and-abhishek-saha)

Answer (score 1):

In `php.ini` there is a max size limit and I replaced the `file.php` for this:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "rar", "zip", "tgz", "iso", "gz",         "img", "exe", );
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/rar")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("/var/www/file/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "/var/www/file/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "/file/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

     }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the name of the file...i.e:

```
<input type="file" name="myfile[]" multiple><br>
```

While u are accessing it in php code as `$_FILES["file"]["type"]`. Change the name to `file` instead of `myfile[]`. Change to :

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple><br>
```

There are still some more errors though